FedEx API returns the same test label
I create a shipment with the test environment https://apis-sandbox.fedex.com/ship/v1/shipments. I change the request body (the shipper/recipient data) but always get the same response with the same shipping labels.
For example, the shipper data:
{
  "contact": {
    "personName": "Jan Kowalski",
    "companyName": "Shipper Polska Sp. z o.o.",
    "phoneNumber": "+48221234567"
  },
  "address": {
    "streetLines": ["ul. Królewska 10"],
    "city": "Warszawa",
    "stateOrProvinceCode": "",
    "postalCode": "00-065",
    "countryCode": "PL"
  }
}

The response is always https://developer.fedex.com/api/content/dam/fedex-com/irc/SV_labels/USE_SCHEDULED_PICKUP_INTERNATIONAL_PRIORITY_YOUR_PACKAGING_SENDER_URL_ONLY_PAPER_85X11_TOP_HALF_LABEL.pdf
The API Certification says to

Use the shipper/recipient address information when creating sample
labels for evaluation.

So should the test label data be dynamic?

"So should the test label data be dynamic?"  This is probably a question for Fedex. I can understand why they want to potentially limit this functionality in the test API unless it's obvious that the label is a test.
